# On parsing gson.toJson(obj) giving null

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, inner-classes

wWhen I am passing object of local-inner-class `ShipAddress` to `toJson()` method of `Gson` class this is returning null on parsing it.

```
public class CrusialDateRest {

  public String getShippingAddressesDetails() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try {

       Collection<ImplAddress> savedAddressBeans = new ArrayList<ImplAddress>();
       Collection<CtFlexField> countryFields = new ArrayList<CtFlexField>();
       Collection<CtFlexField> debitorFields = new ArrayList<CtFlexField>();

       class ShipAddress{
           Collection<ImplAddress> savedAddressBean = new ArrayList<ImplAddress>();
           Collection<CtFlexField> countryField = new ArrayList<CtFlexField>();
           Collection<CtFlexField> debitorField = new ArrayList<CtFlexField>();
            ShipAddress( Collection<ImplAddress> savedAddressBeans, Collection<CtFlexField> countryFields,Collection<CtFlexField> debitorFields){
                savedAddressBean=savedAddressBeans;
                countryField=countryFields;
                debitorField=debitorFields;
            }
        }


         String addrId= XmlParser.getNodeValue(address, Statics.BUYFLOW_NAMESPACE, "AddressId");
         String addrStreet1 = XmlParser.getNodeValue(address, Statics.BUYFLOW_NAMESPACE, "AddrStreet1");
         String addrStreet2 = XmlParser.getNodeValue(address, Statics.BUYFLOW_NAMESPACE, "AddrStreet2");    
         String addrStreet3 = XmlParser.getNodeValue(address, Statics.BUYFLOW_NAMESPACE, "AddrStreet3");

        ImplAddress impladdress = new ImplAddress();
        impladdress.setAddressId(addrId);
        impladdress.setAddrStreet1(addrStreet1);
        impladdress.setAddrStreet2(addrStreet2);
        impladdress.setAddrStreet3(addrStreet3);
        savedAddressBeans.add(impladdress);

        }
     CtFlexField[] flexField =  flexFields.getFlexField();
      for (CtFlexField flex : flexField) {
         if(flex.getBundle().equalsIgnoreCase("Countries")){
             countryFields.add(flex);
         }
         else if(flex.getBundle().equalsIgnoreCase("CommonBundle")){
             debitorFields.add(flex);
         }
     }

      jsonResponse = gson.toJson(new ShipAddress(savedAddressBeans,countryFields,debitorFields));
      OUT.debug("jsonResponse--"+jsonResponse);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      OUT.error("rest method getShippingAddresses error", e);
    }
    return jsonResponse;
  }
}
```

Should I make inner class outside method?

Or is this a serialization issue?

Comment: can you please add the output as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a visibility issue.

Either move `ShipAddress` into its own class file, or make it a `public static` inner class.

Note that public static classes cannot be declared inside of methods, you would have to move the class out of `getShippingAddressDetails()`method.